# B2c Custom policy for sign in

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I'm looking to create a custom policy in the following scenario

- User is created in tenant by job that has custom attributes for users
  case reference and Ni Number (i know how to do this)
- User gets a sign in page. There is no sign up page
- Sign in page has email, case ref, ni number that the user is required
  to enter
- sign in validation validates case ref and ni number against what is
  held in B2C tenant

Looking at microsofts docs is baffling... whoever thought getting devs to edit and create the xml policy files was good idea beggars belief

Is it actually possible to validate against the info in the tenant through some sort of technical validation profile or something?

Answer (score 0):

Create a [self-asserted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/self-asserted-technical-profile) page with case ref, ni number etc. as output claims i.e they will appear on the form.

Add this page to the user journey after sign-in ("login-NonInteractive").

Read the user attributes ("AAD-UserReadUsingxxx).

You can [compare](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/string-transformations) the claims in the journey. Maybe easier to call a [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/restful-technical-profile) to validate the information.

If good, send the JWT (the standard "SendClaims"). If not, display an error.

Comment: I'd already got it 'largely' working using an API connector ... I was ideally trying to avoid writing any validation API that goes against our internal DBs but if i have to then I have to .. I'd actually just come across your medium articles before reading your answer.. will have a look at your answer in more depth today .. cheers